# How can I check if a year is a leap year using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG9DD.png) with this code:

```
is_leap_year = False
not_leap_year = True 

input_year = int(input())

if (input_year % 4 == 0 or input_year % 400 == 0):
    print(input_year, '- leap year')

elif (input_year % 4 != 0 and input_year % 400 != 0):
    print(input_year, '- not a leap year')
```

Why is my code still reading `1900` as a leap year?

Comment: because the remainder of 1900 divided by 4 is zero!

Answer (score 4):

Divisibility by 400 is an exception to the rule that years divisible by 100 are *not* leap years, which itself is an exception to the rule that years divisible by 4 are leap years. If you wrote it out in sequence, you might write

```
if year % 400 == 0:  # Some centuries are leap years...
    print("leap year")
elif year % 100 == 0: # ... but most are not ...
    print("not leap year")
elif year % 4 == 0:   # ... even though other divisibly-by-four years are
    print("leap year")
else:
    print("not leap year")
```

or work your way up

```
if year % 4 != 0:
    print("not a leap year")
elif year % 100 != 0:
    print("leap year")
elif year % 400 != 0:
    print("not a leap year")
else:
    print("leap year")
```

Combining these into a single test would be something like

```
if year % 4 != 0 or (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0):
    print("not a leap year")
else:
    print("leap year")
```

which I find a little harder to follow than a series of simple tests.

(Given the nature of a solar year, making *every* year divisible by 400 a leap year is *also* a problem, though not as big a one as making every century year a leap year. People wanting to avoid drifts over the millenia will propose additional exceptions like "years divisible by 4000, or 40,000, or something, should not be leap years"; no official rule exists yet, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Because 1900 % 4 is actually 0, so the first if conditional is True ( True or False is True) and then it doesn't execute the second if block because is an elif (else if, and since the first was True, there is no need to execute the else part).

Answer (score 1):

> Try like this!

```
year = int(input("Input year: "))

if year % 4 == 0:
    print("Year is leap.")
    if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0:
        print("Year is common.")
else:
    print("Year is common.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the first condition `input_year % 4 == 0` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

1900/4= 475 => input_year%4 == 0 is True => for your code 1900 is a leap year

1901/4 = 475,25 => input_year%4 == 0 is false => for your code 1901 is not a leap year

Answer (score 0):

1900 is not a leap year, your calculation is not correct.

here is the code for leap year calculation:

```
if (year % 4) == 0:
   if (year % 100) == 0:
       if (year % 400) == 0:
           print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
       else:
           print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
   else:
       print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
else:
   print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simplified function taking advantage of Truthy/Falsely

````
    if not(year % 400) or (not(year % 4) and year % 100) : return True
    return False```

print(isLeapYear(1900)) # False
print(isLeapYear(1896)) # True
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "or" use "and" in the first if statement.
Both conditions need to be met.

Comment: This answer is lacking in detail. Consider revising to include more detail and a code snippet.

Comment: @codingCat for real?

Comment: @DeepakKamat yes. Your comment is out of context. Were you referring to the original message, which does use and/or, or are you responding to the to another answer, in which case you should have posted as a comment to that answer rather than as a new answer.